# Randomized list with no repeats or duplicates from list of specific numbers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with 1,179+/- individual part numbers that currently populate Column "A", randomized by =RAND() in column "B", and auto fill several groups of cells in Column "I". 5 blocks with 5 parts each 5 separate times (125 parts total).

Essentially, 5 randomized parts each day (5) of the week for 5 people.
The randomized distribution is an important process so I have to keep that and the random distribution is changed with each F9 key press.

Once a part number is pulled from Column "A" and populated into column "I", I need that part to not show up again in the randomization and population of column "I" until all of the 1,179 part numbers have been distributed at least once.

I attempted VBA code that should remove duplicate numbers. It should run a check on numbers in column "A" against column "I" and remove the duplicate number from column "A" thus, in my mind, preventing it from showing back up.
I couldn't get any "RemoveDuplicates" codes to work.

Another issue is, when a cell is manually cleared, it populates column "I" with a zero rather than a number still in column "A". I'm not sure if this is because the numbers in column "I" are populated using an index formula (=@INDEX($A$1:$A$1178,RANK(B2,$B$1:$B$1178) thus not "actual" numbers and the items in column "A" are linked to the RAND() function of column "B".

TL:DR- Is there a way to randomize a list of items from one column into another column with no duplicates among them and never having the same item appear more than once through each randomization (F9) until all items have been eventually cycled through?

VBA code used:

```vb
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 9) , Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

The code runs but doesn't remove any duplicates from column "A" after randomization to prevent those numbers from showing again.

Preview of columns, numbers, and randomization section
[image]

Comment: Edited to include the requested material. @braX

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I would use:

- create a random number in a new column (looks like you have done that)
- order the column you care about by the random column (this will be a random order)
- take from the list of numbers you care about sequentially in this order -- you will never duplicate because it is your original list.